# Deleted wallpapers still showing up in "Desktop"

Tags: desktop, wallpaper, app-shortcuts

I deleted some pictures that I set as wallpaper but they're still showing up in my Desktop(Applications->System Setting->Desktop). I tried looking for them to see where they are stored. I have checked:

```
.cache/wallpapers 

usr/share/backgrounds
```

And I also disabled hidden files as well and I couldn't find them. Anyone know where they are stored?

Comment: have you deleted default wallpapers?

Comment: Actually I found it. The actual elementary OS stores wallpaper cache for Applications->System Setting->Desktop in /home/yourName/.local/share/backgrounds

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I found it. Elementary OS stores wallpaper cache for Applications->System Setting->Desktop in:

```
~/.local/share/backgrounds
```

Really confusing to find especially after googling for solutions and finding multiple places where wallpapers can be stored.

Comment: Nice, that can be written as  `~/.local/share/backgrounds`